# Problems with pushing to github repository from Eclipse: Auth fail

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I followed the steps from **[Egit user guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Remote#Push_Upstream)**, but I get an error message with auth fail.

What I do:
I have copied the public key from `Window > Preferences > Network Connections > SSH2 > Key Management` to GitHub under account settings

Then I do
`Team > Push`...
I enter the `git@github.com:....` uri and click next. But then I get the error:

```
**Cannot get remote repository refs  
Reason: git@github.com:....  : Auth fail**
```

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Now it works in Eclipse + Github. Unchecked the checkbox store in secure store. But in Zend Studio + my unfuddle account it is still not working. Here the error message is ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Repository read access denied  git@derk.unfuddle.com:derk/demuno.git: ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Repository read access denied

Comment: and also solved this. It seems like every unfuddle repository has to be associated with a project

Answer (score 9):

Old question, but for future reference:

Make sure you did **setup a push remote**. It worked for me when I got both the *Cannot get remote repository refs*-problems ("... Passphrase for..." and "Auth fail" in the "Push..." dialog).

Provided that you already:

1. Setup your SSH keys with Github (Window > Preferences > General > Network Connections > SSH2)
2. Setup your local repository (you can follow [this guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide) for that)
3. Created a Github repository ([same guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Github_Tutorial))

... here's how you do it:

- Go to the **Git Repositories view** (Window > Show View > Other > Git Repositories)
- Expand your Repository and **right click Remotes** --> **"Create Remote"**
- "Remote Name": origin, "Configure push": checked --> **click "OK"**
- Click the **"Change..."** button
- **Paste your git URI** and select protocol **ssh** --> **click "Finish"**
- Now, **click "Save and Push"** and NOW you should get a password prompt --> **enter the public key passphrase** here (provided that you DID (and you should) setup a passphrase to your public key) --> **click "OK"**
- Now you should get a confirmation window saying "Pushed to *YourRepository* - origin" --> **click "OK"**
- **[Push to upstream](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Push_Upstream)**, but this time **use "Configured remote repository"** as your Destination Git repository
- Go get yourself a well earned cup of coffee!

Comment: This didn't do it for me.

Answer (score 4):

Check my solution from this related question:
["Auth Failed" error with EGit and GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601805/auth-problem-with-egit-and-github/7629938#7629938)

Briefly: set GIT_SSH environment variable with a path to the system ssh executable before launching Eclipse. Far from nice but works.

For Ubuntu:

```
> export GIT_SSH=/usr/bin/ssh
> eclipse
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally fixed this on my platform (mainly was a key issue but also critical not to have a leading slash before the repo path in the dialog pictured above). You can see more details in my post here, if you like:

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=648905&S=9bcfa96ab726d744d41a19c7fb02d723#msg_648905

Good luck!

Melissa

Comment: Thanks Melissa! Setting it up first in the git repositories view worked for me when nothing else did

Answer (score 2):

DO not forget to add .git to the repository name in the URI : field

for example if ur username is Decoderx and git repository name is foo
**URI :https://github.com/Decoderx/foo.git**

and not **"https://github.com/Decoderx/foo"**  this solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and follow [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html#github_push), using the **git+ssh** protocol:

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/path_to/repo.git.github
```

Just `git@github.com` alone wouldn't work.

[image]

Comment: Ok, I don't have the protocol option git+ssh in Eclipse. I tried with ssh but it gives the same error

Comment: @Derk: what os are you using? What eclipse version and what EGit version?

Answer (score -1):

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Github_Tutorial

Comment: Linking back to the tutorial that the OP already linked to, and without a comment, is far from productive.