# EGit - SSH Fails at Passphrase (when connecting to GitHub)

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

I am using Eclipse Indigo RC4 with EGit (bundled). I have a project which I have committed to my local repository, and now I want to push from that to a remote repository I have in GitHub.

Pushing / Pulling from the command line tools works fine (I have configured RSA key based SSH authentication).

But when I try to push from EGit (via SSH pointed to GitHub), I get a prompt to enter my pass phrase. But when I enter the correct pass phrase, it prompts again for the same (note: username appears as git because that's the default when using GitHub. I guess that wouldn't be a issue).

Under Eclipse preferences, I have double checked to ensure that it is configured to use the RSA tokens I have generated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Got it sorted out by following this link http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/197428/.

I created an environment variable `GIT_SSH` which points to `/usr/bin/ssh` (which was the SSH implementation I was using in command line) and started Eclipse. When this environment variable was present, Eclipse connected using my shell's SSH tool and there was no prompt for pass phrase and it worked fine.

Comment: I am having issues doing this, where do I place the environmental variable, the exact line I need please?

Comment: @Seth That depends on your operating system Seth. In my case, I am using Ubuntu, so I modified the `/etc/environment` (you need super-user privileges for that) file and added the line `GIT_SSH="/usr/bin/ssh"` as the last line into it, and restart the machine. If you are using Windows, check out this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519. In any case, a quick Google on "How to set environment variable in _Your-OS-Name_" will get you going. Hope this helps. Good Luck !

Comment: same problem, same solution! Tks a lot!

Comment: FYI but not to be a stickler, you generally shouldn't edit /etc/environment and should instead edit the .profile in your home directory. Adding the line export GIT_SSH=`which ssh` will typically work across most platforms.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Yeah you are right. I am used to editing /etc/environment because changes I do there are available across all accounts. But then again I have only one account in my machine, and I could have just used the .profile instead :)

Answer (score 13):

Even simpler is to update the JSch bundle to 0.1.44 from eclipse orbit repository (p2 software site): http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20110523182458/repository/

The underlying problem is actually that JSch < 0.1.44 does not support the newer encryption scheme AES-128:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=326526

Comment: That fixed it for me (Ubuntu 11.04). Why wouldn't they backport that into the current stable release? Frustrating.

Comment: @adietisheim Many thanks! Updating the JSch package worked for me as well!! :)

Answer (score 2):

On Eclipse Juno, Jsch is already > 1.44 and yet the problem still happens (for me). I also tried setting GIT_SSH and this didn't work either. My previous keys had been generated by ssh-keygen, I can only guess that this doesn't generate a suitable key.

What I did that worked was this:

- Use **Eclipse** to generate a new DSA key - creating a 1024 bit key
  Eclipse->Preferences->General->Network Connections->SSH2->Key Management

  [It might work with RSA I didn't try]
- Copy the generated public key to the remote repo
- Click the [Save Private Key] button without entering a passphrase
- RESTART ECLIPSE

Eclipse/EGit will now synch with the remote Git Repo, without requiring a passphrase  - phew!