# Egit Refuses to accept id_rsa

Tags: eclipse, git, ssh-keys, egit

I'm a first time git user trying to setup egit in Eclipse so I can continue to easily code through Eclipse. Problem is, every time I try to clone a repo through egit, it gives me the error "Cannot list available branches. Reason: ssh://git@github.com:22 Passphrase for /Users/elifinkelshteyn/.ssh/id_rsa." This is really strange as I can clone through terminal using that same id_rsa just fine, and I've verified in Eclipse ssh properties that it is trying to use the correct key. What gives?

Comment: As VonC says below, this is a current bug, but only in the latest nightly builds. I was able to fix my problem by rolling back to the latest stable build, at which point I was correctly prompted for my password. *If anyone else experiences this problem, just roll back to the latest stable*.

Comment: This _could_ be considered a duplicate of SO question [EGit - SSH Fails at Passphrase (when connecting to GitHub)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6316014/1020470)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to confirm: this is a current bug ([issue 353561](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353561)).
And passphrase might still be a problem depending on the encryption you used when creating your key ([bug 326526](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=326526)).

However, passphrase are supposed to be supported (as the [Egit user guide mentions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Remote#Eclipse_SSH_Configuration)).

Answer (score 7):

if you get a prompt for the passphrase but eclipse doesn't accept the passphrase, try the following:

set the GIT_SSH environment variable to your ssh client e.g. by adding

```
export GIT_SSH=/usr/bin/ssh
```

to your .bash_rc

on Mac OSX, open terminal and type:

```
cd
mkdir .MacOSX
cd .MacOSX
echo "" > environment.plist
open environment.plist
```

add a KEY=GIT_SSH with VALUE=/usr/bin/ssh
and save the file.

After relogin to your account, it should work.

Comment: I ran into this problem with Ubuntu 12.04, Eclipse Helios, OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 and eGit 2.1.0.201209190230-r. Eclipse was prompting me for my passphrase on my id_rsa private key and would not accept my input. I followed the [these instructions][helpful_ticket] and ran the following in a command line and added it to my ~/.bashrc: export GIT_SSH=/usr/bin/ssh After restarting Eclipse I was prompted for a passphrase by the Gnome keymanager instead. My passphrase was accepted and I was able to connect to my github repo. [helpful_ticket]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7901786/1304537

Answer (score 3):

As VonC says, it's a bug that the SSH implementation that EGit uses can't handle anything but 3DES encrypted private keys.
If you're like me, you have AES encrypted keys, so it just fails to decrypt them.
There is a comment in that bug report, here's a link directly to the comment https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=326526#c9

That comment provided a working workaround: recent versions of EGit honour the GIT_SSH environment variable, setting that to /usr/bin/ssh or even plink.exe if you're on windows should solve the issue.

Comment: Another fix is to update JSch (the eclipse/EGit ssh implementation) to version 1.44, that _does_ decrypt AES passwords, and is explained in the bug [@Lynden Shields](http://stackoverflow.com/users/78823/lynden-shields) notes, and also in the SO question [EGit - SSH Fails at Passphrase (when connecting to GitHub)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7032313/1020470)

Answer (score 1):

A considerable amount of time has passed since the OP and I still had the same problem. For those who still has this problem, this might help:

Make sure you did **setup a push remote**. It worked for me when I got both the *Cannot get remote repository refs*-problems ("... Passphrase for..." and "Auth fail" in the "Push..." dialog).

Provided that you already:

1. Setup your SSH keys with Github (Window > Preferences > General > Network Connections > SSH2)
2. Setup your local repository (you can follow [this guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide) for that)
3. Created a Github repository ([same guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Github_Tutorial))

... here's how you do it:

- Go to the **Git Repositories view** (Window > Show View > Other > Git Repositories)
- Expand your Repository and **right click Remotes** --> **"Create Remote"**
- "Remote Name": origin, "Configure push": checked --> **click "OK"**
- Click the **"Change..."** button
- **Paste your git URI** and select protocol **ssh** --> **click "Finish"**
- Now, **click "Save and Push"** and NOW you should get a password prompt --> **enter the public key passphrase** here (provided that you DID (and you should) setup a passphrase to your public key) --> **click "OK"**
- Now you should get a confirmation window saying "Pushed to *YourRepository* - origin" --> **click "OK"**
- **[Push to upstream](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Push_Upstream)**, but this time **use "Configured remote repository"** as your Destination Git repository
- Go get yourself a well earned cup of coffee!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your /Users/elifinkelshteyn/.ssh/id_rsa file requires a password, and I'm not sure that the ssh implementation in Eclipse knows how to prompt you for one. It's tickling the back of my brain that there's probably an ssh-auth package you need to install for the mac so that it can prompt, and if you can find out more about that, it's probably ideal. However, a workaround in the short term is to generate a new rsa key that doesn't use a password, upload that to github, and set eclipse to use it.

Comment: Protection of your private key has nothing to do with the public key from the keypair which you upload to GitHub.