# Transport Error: Cannot get remote repository refs

Tags: github, ssh, egit

I'm getting following error while trying to push my local git repo to github repo. There is no problem accessing my remote github repo from terminal but EGit is not working.

[image: EGit Error]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[“Auth Failed” error with EGit and GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601805/auth-failed-error-with-egit-and-github/7629938#7629938) solved this problem.

In Brief,

```
cd ~
echo "export GIT_SSH=/usr/bin/ssh" >> .profile
```

And then restart Eclipse to take effect.

Comment: And on windows?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ssh URL, I used Http Url with authentication.