# Eclipse forget my Git password and username everytime after I do a push

Tags: eclipse, git, github

Eclipse Platform Version: 4.3.2.v20140221-1852 Build id: M20140221-1700

Eclipse Git Version: 3.3.2.201403251439

Eclipse forgets my git username and password every time after I do a push. What is the problem?

I have tried the methods in [How to make Egit remember password and username?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331166/how-to-make-egit-remember-password-and-username):

1) Go to the Git Perspective -> Expand your Project -> Expand Remotes -> Expand the remote you want to save your password.

2) Right-click on the Fetch or Push -> Select Change Credentials...

3) Enter username and password -> Select Ok

But it did not work for me. My problem is that Eclipse can temporarily remember my username and password as shown in the following figure:

[image]

But after I do a push, Eclipse will forget all the Credentials (username and password):

[image]
[image]

Eclipse asks me for the username and password every time I do a push even if the first figure shows it has temporarily remembered my password.

[image]
[image]

Helps would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem myself. It should be a bug in the version of Eclipse Git I was using. When I updated to the latest Eclipse Git, the problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

Secure Storage is your direct provider of credentials.

So, go to:

- Window->Preferences->General->Network
- Change Provider to "Direct"

This should really be the default since Secure Storage is the default provider in Eclipse.

You can also change the git preferences to not pop up confirmation dialogs and the overall result will be a very fast workflow.