# Error during push using Egit: "Connection reset by peer: socket write error"

Tags: java, git, eclipse, github, egit

When trying to push a branch using Egit to a repository that I own, I get the following error:

> Can't connect to any repository: https://github.com/name/rep.git
>   (https://github.com/name/rep.git: Connection reset by peer: socket
>   write error)

- The credentials are correct.
- Happens to all branches I try to push to that repo.
- I can connect to the repository on GitHub.
- The push fails at 95-96%.
- I was able to push to that repository before. Not sure what changed.

Using:

Eclipse  Version: 2020-03 (4.15)
Build id: I20200305-0155

Eclipse EGit    Git integration for Eclipse 5.7.0.202003110725-r    org.eclipse.egit

Comment: Can you push using the SSH URL? You can continue to fetch using https.

Comment: @nitind What do I need to change in order to do that?

Comment: When you go to your repository in the GitHub web UI, hit the green Clone or download button and look for a Use SSH link in the upper right of the popup. It'll show you the remote to push to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to download Eclipse again, install EGit, load the workspace, and then the push worked as usual. It seems that something happened to the installation.

Opening the old installation now also works again.

Comment: Yes, probably the secure storage that I mentioned in my answer included the wrong credential.

Comment: @VonC I already deleted the secure storage and re-added the credentials before asking here, it did not help.

Comment: And what does `git config credential.helper` return?

Comment: @VonC Where do I execute this? I don't have git installed, only EGit. Also, I reopened the older Eclipse and now it also works.

Comment: OK, so something else must have been reset by the new installation.

Answer (score 1):

In the [remote repository view](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Remote_Repositories), you can see the URL used and modify it if you need to make a test with SSH.

But check first if, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58524976/6309), a saved password in secure storage doesn't match with the typed one.
See

```
Window > Preferences > Security > Secure Storage > Contents Tab > [Default Secure Storage] > GIT
```

From there, you should be able to check if a password was stored for github.com.