# How to Setup New Git Authentication in Elcipse IDE

Tags: git, eclipse

I recently got an email from Github telling me that git will be moving away from passwords and towards authentication keys for committing and pushing changes. How would I set up this authentication key and tell Eclipse to use this key instead of the password I gave it originally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a [PAT (Personnal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token)

Second, in Eclipse, delete your current credential, and on the next push, Eclipse will ask for them again (GitHub username, and your token -- PAT -- as a password)

See "[How to make Egit remember password and username?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58524976/6309)"

- From Eclipse toolbar navigate to `Window > Preferences > Security > Secure Storage > Contents Tab > [Default Secure Storage] > GIT >` "whatever github url"
- Select the url and delete the current user.
- restart Eclipse