# Eclipse Egit and GitHub authentication deprecation

Tags: eclipse, github, https, token, egit

I'm using Eclipse (Egit) and GitHub and I'm receiving this notice:

```
Hi,

You recently used a password to access the repository with git using JGit/5.10.0.202012080955-r.

Basic authentication using a password to Git is deprecated and will soon no longer work. Visit https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information around suggested workarounds and removal dates.
```

Currently I'm using HTTPS connection with user and password and probably I have to switch to a HTTPS token, but how can I configure Eclipse/Egit for an HTTPS token?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Github deprecated the authentication of using your personal account password. You will need to change your git credentials in Eclipse to use a personal access token instead of using your Github account password.

[Link](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) for creating a personal access token.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331166/how-to-make-egit-remember-password-and-username#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20the%20Git%20Perspective,username%20and%20password%20%2D%3E%20Select%20Ok) for changing your credentials in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, was not clear to me I have to use that token as password and keep my user.