# GIT SSH authentication failed via Eclipse but works when git clone is used manually?

Tags: eclipse, macos, git, ssh, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to clone a git repository using Eclipse, while the path/id_rsa etc when manual command is used. It fails when I try accessing the same path using Eclipse.

Error Message

"
Please Check:
Network Connection Settings

Network Connection->SSH2 Eclipse preferences."

Both my settings are default , is there any change that u guys recommend ? Google search/previous stack overflow questions did not give me any useful pointers.
Here is the tutorial that I am using
http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html#github_clone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601805/auth-failed-error-with-egit-and-github
This problem seems similar to mine.
I think the main point here is the step 2 , since I assume the key that I presently use would prolly be of 2048 length.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (**Auth fail** error while pull repository files)

```
Window > Show View > Other > Git Repositories
Expand your Repository
```

There you have **orgin**

Right click **orgin** >> **Configure push...**

There you need to add URI with your credentials

[image: eclipse screen shot].

Add all details above and save it. This solve the auth problem for me.