# EGit authentication failure with EC2 git server

Tags: git, authentication, ssh, amazon-ec2, egit

I use an EC2 instance as a Git server. I am able to push / pull my repo from terminal. But when I use EGit to push / pull my repo, I got the "Auth fail" problem.

In the Git configuration of EGit, I set

```
URI: ec2-user@xx.xx.xx.xx:git-repo-path
Host: xx.xx.xx.xx
Repo path: git-repo-path
```

I tried several protocols: http, ssh, blank. None of them works. I installed AWS toolkit in Eclipse. I set up the credentials of AWS toolkit and I can see my instance in the AWS explore view.

How should I set up the credential of EC2 for EGit?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601805/auth-failed-error-with-egit-and-github