# auth failed with Egit (ssh configuration)

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin, egit, gerrit, ssh-keys

Everything is ok with Gitbash command line : I can execute checkout, git pull, git push ,etc. But it doesn't work with egit.

I use STS 3.6.4.RELEASE and the plugin egit version 3.7

I've added my id_rsa in eclipse(STS) > general > Network connections > SSH2. I've added the right id_rsa in private key field and SSH2 home : .ssh
I've also added the bypass rule in Eclipse proxy rules

But I still have the same error on fetch, commit or other commands :

> ssh://"username"@"host":29418/"project_folder": Auth fail

stacktrace :

> org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException:
>   ssh://jjack@aurora.credi-ouest.cnamts.fr:29418/navigo: Auth fail  at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:139)     at
>   org.eclipse.egit.core.op.FetchOperation.run(FetchOperation.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.fetch.FetchOperationUI.execute(FetchOperationUI.java:103)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.fetch.FetchOperationUI$1.runInWorkspace(FetchOperationUI.java:123)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54) Caused
>   by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException:
>   ssh://jjack@aurora.credi-ouest.cnamts.fr:29418/navigo: Auth fail  at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:159)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:136)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.(TransportGitSsh.java:262)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:161)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:136)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
>     at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1138)
>     at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:130)    ...
>   5 more Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail    at
>   com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:512)     at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:116)
>     ... 12 more

My coworker has the same configuration in eclipse but it works for him.
I've already looked at this SO answer : [auth failed error with egit and github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601805/auth-failed-error-with-egit-and-github)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put the wrong element in .ssh/id_rsa. I had put the public key in openssh format instead of the private key in "putty" format.
The easiest way to fix it was to import the id_rsa.ppk in egit using "general > Network connections > SSH2 >key management > load existing key" then save private key in id_rsa file.