# Error writing request body to server - eGit - Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin, egit

I am using BitBucket. https://VibhuDadhichi@bitbucket.org/VibhuDadhichi/disrupt.git

I cloned a project using eGit to my local and added a project to it using eclipse "Add Existing project to workspace". Ran the project on the system. Everything worked fine. Now when I want to push the project to the master. It stops at 40% - **Error writing request body to server**. No change.

I can see the changes on my local git folder.

I tried increasing the size of the buffer. It's not that big file.

https.postBuffer=524288000 in the git/config file.

New to version control. Please help.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, but nobody helped to solve this

Comment: Add entry to "http" as well. http.postBuffer=524288000

Comment: I tried this but now I'm getting another error "insufficient data written"

Comment: Send screenshots I can help

Answer (score 0):

@DvD I solved the problem connecting through SSH. First, I generated the private and public key, then deployed the key on github and copied the public key file to the .ssh folder within windows and I could push the project.

For SSH key generation on Eclipse please refer to: ["Auth Failed" error with EGit and GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601805/auth-failed-error-with-egit-and-github)

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, we follow below steps:
Right click on your GIT Project and go to

```
Properties>Configuration>Add Entry
```

Set below properties

```
Key=https.postBuffer
Value=524288000
```

Restart Eclipse IDE