# Why does Eclipse Throw TFS Git Repository Authentication Error?

Tags: git, tfs, salesforce

I am getting the following Error when I Try GIT Clone from TFS using Eclipse

```
authentication not supported:
```

1. Installed GIT in EClipse IDE
2. Clone GIT and filled in the details.
3. when i click next i get the following Error

Has Any one ever faced this error?
Would it need a configuration change on eclipse or TFS?

Comment: Take a look at the url you're trying to clone from and make sure its in the correct format.

Comment: Did you take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601805/auth-failed-error-with-egit-and-github